# Resources management and a cumbersome situation

Tags: human-resources, prioritization

Given the following scenario (as I am new to this forum please excuse my noobish style to put the question).

- A customer project (lead by project manager K) buys a full time person P as agreed with a service provider executive E. Inbetween is a coordinator C.
- P does not participate full time because C "does not know about agreement with E" and there are other tasks in other K-related projects to do for P (as previously agreed with K).

What is the correct escalation/mediation way? Is this maybe a prioritization problem on customer side (K)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The course of action depends on which role you are in. Reading between the lines, I believe you're interested in how C should engage / escalate in this situation.

Depending on the relationship between the parties, I would have a quick word with K and clarify expectations for how P's time should be allocated across the various projects. C should be aware of the impact (schedule / cost) of P not being available to engage on each project so the discussion with K can come to a conclusion with clear actions to pursue.

If other projects are at risk, identify possible mitigation(s) that the project manager can sign off on (e.g. replacement talent, schedule adjustments, etc).